# Connect to mysql docker service from custom wordpress config file

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I want to connect my docker mysql service to my docker wordpress service via a custom wp-config file. This seems like a simple thing to do, but I can find no straightforward answer.

I just want to know what to type as the value for this declaration in the wp-config.php file:
`define( 'DB_HOST', what_do_i_type_here );`

I've been able to connect via `0.0.0.0:3307` on my host machine, and I can connect using the wordpress image environment variables `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST`, etc, but I haven't been able to figure out how to manually connect via the wp-config file.

These are a few of the hosts I've tried:

```
0.0.0.0:3307
127.0.0.1:3307
172.23.0.1:3307
docker.for.mac.localhost:3307
host.docker.internal:3307
```

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    links:
      - db:mysql
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./wp-config.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php
      - ./wp-blog-header.php:/var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php
    restart: always
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db:mysql
    ports:
      - "8009:80"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: wordpress
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Here are the configurations in my wp-config file:

```
# Database Configuration
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'wordpress' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress' );
define( 'DB_HOST', '0.0.0.0:3307' );

// define( 'DB_HOST_SLAVE', '127.0.0.1' );
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_unicode_ci');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this page:
[Networking in compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Each container can reach the other by its hostname.
You may use `define( 'DB_HOST', db:3306 );` in wp-config.php file.

Comment: Thank you! There was another issue with my database that was causing a problem. This worked.

Comment: Small correction: `define( 'DB_HOST', 'db:3306' );`